# Bitsadmin denies access for download

Tags: batch-file, download

Hello dear stackoverflow community, in my recent project I tried to download a file with the bitsadmin batch function which looked like this :

call bitsadmin /transfer NETFX  /download /priority normal http://example.com/example.exe c:\test\example.exe

I tried to execute it but it gave me the error :

> Access denied.

Now I don't really know what to do and need a fix/help.
I wrote this in a rush so please don't be harsh to me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the task with proper elevation?
You can also try the following command

```
bitsadmin.exe /transfer Explorers /download /priority FOREGROUND https://example.com/filename.exe %appdata%\filename.exe
```